# Check the validity of a call to os.system using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Is there any way out to observe that the system call is valid or not if we go for a system call with an argument taken from user in Python 3 ? For example

**os.system('pwd')** will return **true** but

**os.system('abc')** will return **false**.

Can we check the same using sub-process ?

Comment: What do you mean by valid

Comment: @NickA Please see the example i.e. 'pwd' is a valid system call which gives the present working directory but 'abc' is not.